# Python NetworkX : Graph update after node contraction

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I created a networkX digraph as follows:

```
import networkx.algorithms.isomorphism as iso
import networkx as nx
G1 = nx.DiGraph()
G1.add_nodes_from(range(1,7))

# Creating Acyclic Directed Graph
G1.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(1,4),(4,5),(5,6)])
```

When plotted, G1 looks like following:

[image]

Now I want to contract node 2 in node 1 which I am doing using NetowrkX's "contract_node" function. I plot the graph and print all nodes and edges after contraction.

```
H = nx.contracted_nodes(G1,1,2,self_loops=False)
print(H.nodes)
print(H.edges)
```

[image]

It simply collapses node 2 in node 1 and all edges between 2 and 1 are removed, as if node 2 never existed thereby making node index non contiguous [1,3,4,5,6]. Instead, I want to update the graph after node contraction and pull back all nodes above the contracted node (2 in this case) so that my node list and edge list look like following:

```
Node List : [1,2,3,4,5]
Edge List : [(1,3),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]
```

Basically update node idx of all nodes above the contracted node by number of contracted nodes (by 1 in this case as I am contracting a single node) and update respective links.

Is there a NetworkX function to do this? If not, what is the best way to achieve this? Eventually, I would like to fuse nodes in an ordered graph (sorted node and edge lists) and then compare it with with other other ordered graphs (sorted node and edge lists) for Isomorphism. NetworkX's isomorphism functions provide boolean result (Graphs are Isomorphic or Graphs are NOT Isomorphic) but they do NOT provide any information on point of divergence between 2 Non-Isomorphic graphs. Is there any NetworkX support for this ? Given a start node, for finding point of divergence, I was planning to get all edge lists using nx.edge_bfs() for 2 ordered graphs and compare them to find the point of divergence for further investigation. This approach would fail if node idx are not contiguous. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nx.relabel_nodes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html#networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes) to relabel your nodes and edges.
Example:

```
>>> mapping = dict(zip(sorted(H), range(1,len(H)+1)))
>>> mapping
{1: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 4, 6: 5}
>>> H2 = nx.relabel_nodes(H, mapping)
>>> H2.nodes
NodeView((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
>>> H2.edges
OutEdgeView([(1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)])
```

Comment: Wow ! It didn't occur to me that relabeling would update entire graph data structure (nodes and links).  This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @abc !